# JDBC working in android emulator but not on real device?

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I'm using Android Studio to develop an android application that connects to Oracle database using JDBC drivers.

**Problem:**

Works fine when compiled and run on the Android Emulator (API 26). But when I try to run it on the real device (API 19) it crashes.

It crashes when `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")` is called causing `ClassNotFoundException`.

**Code:**

```
public class LiveDB {
String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
String serverName = "192.168.x.x";
String portNumber = "1521";
String db = "orcl";
String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + db;
String user = "someuser";
String pwd = "somepass";
Connection con = null;

private void openConnection(){
    if(con != null) return;
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        con = null;
    }
}

private void closeConnection(){
    if(con == null) return;
    try{
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        con = null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<Student> searchStudents(String input){
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    openConnection();
    try {
        String query = Student.getQuery(input);
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet set = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (set.next()) {
            //Getting data from set and show it.
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        con = null;
    }
    closeConnection();
    return students;
}
}
```

Comment: This is likely because the device doesn't have the required library on board, and your emulator has access to the library in your workspace.

Comment: No, I've tried it on a real device (API 26) and it also works. I think it has something to do it with android version. But I'm putting jars in lib folder, why they won't work on Android API 19 but works on Android API 26.

Comment: You should not use JDBC drivers from an Android application. Create a webservice that connects to the database and let your Android application talk to the webservice.

Comment: I know about web services but that is not the answer. I want to do it with JDBC drivers as my android app will not be asking for too much data. And also consider the strange problem that JDBC drivers work fine on Android API 26 but not on API 19. I don't think that API versions have anything to do with `Class.forName()` call but it gives **ClassNotFoundException**.

Comment: I don't think those drivers exist further back then api level 26, or at least not that far back.